# Is my demonstration for $ \lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)}(x^2-y^2)\sin(\frac{1}{x^2+y^2})=0$ correct?

Tags: calculus, limits, multivariable-calculus, proof-verification, alternative-proof

I need to prove that

$$ \lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)}(x^2-y^2)\sin(\frac{1}{x^2+y^2})=0$$

But I'm not sure about my demonstration. I see that $\left|\sin(\frac{1}{x^2+y^2})\right| \le 1$ So I write that

$$\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)}(x^2-y^2)\sin(\frac{1}{x^2+y^2})\le\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)}\left|(x^2-y^2)\sin(\frac{1}{x^2+y^2})\right| \le |(x^2-y^2)|\le|x^2|+|y^2|\le-|x^2|\underbrace{\to0}_{x\to 0}$$

By the Squeeze Theorem

$$\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)}(x^2-y^2)\sin(\frac{1}{x^2+y^2})\le\lim_{x\to0}-|x^2|=0$$

Comment: Everything except the last inequality is fine $|x^2|+|y^2|\leq -|x^2|$ is definitely not true except for $x=y=0$. Why not just finish at $|x^2|+|y^2|\to 0+0=0$ because it's continuous

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All that you have proved was that *if* your limit exists, *then* it cannot be greater than $0$. You can prove that it *is* $0$ using the fact that$$\left\lvert(x^2-y^2)\sin\left(\frac1{x^2+y^2}\right)\right\rvert\leqslant x^2+y^2.$$